# Three plots in two rows aligned at center

Tags: output-formatting, grid-layouts

I wrote this code:

```
UT := 1 + x^2 
VT := t*x^2
WT := t
    Show[GraphicsGrid[{{Plot3D[UT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}], 
        Plot3D[VT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}], 
        Plot3D[WT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}]}}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

I want to export the following, with the third plot centered in the row:

[image: Plot3d]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Where's the tree plot here? And the condition? I am not sure what your title has to do with the contents of the question, or what you would like to achieve.

Comment: `GraphicsGrid[{{Plot3D[UT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}], 
   Plot3D[VT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}]}, {Plot3D[
    WT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}], SpanFromLeft}}, ImageSize -> Large]`?

Comment: Or `Grid[{{Plot3D[UT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}], 
   Plot3D[VT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}]}, {Plot3D[
    WT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}], SpanFromLeft}}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you want the following:

```
UT := 1 + x^2
VT := t*x^2
WT := t
Column[{Row[{Plot3D[UT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}], Plot3D[VT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}]}], 
  Plot3D[WT, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 0.8}]}, Center, BaseStyle -> ImageSizeMultipliers -> 1]
```

[image]